# Не загружаются фотографии на сайт

Tags: php, html

Хочу, чтобы пользователь мог загружать фотографии в папку сайта с помощью кнопки (и для их дальнейшего вывода). Пишет, что фотографию загрузил, хотя в папке сайта она не появляется. Что я сделал не так?

```
<?
include '/db.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/index.php"> 
    <input name="picture" type="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Загрузить">
</form>
<?
$path = '/avatars';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
if (!@copy($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $path . $_FILES['picture']['name'])) {
    echo 'Что-то пошло не так';
    } else {
    echo 'Фотография удачно загружена!';
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
Возможная атака с помощью файловой загрузки!
Некоторая отладочная информация:Array
(
[picture] => Array
    (
        [name] => 4prX6WSofMU.jpg
        [type] => 
        [tmp_name] => 
        [error] => 2
        [size] => 0
    )

)
```

Comment: Уберите @ и поймете в чем ошибка.

Comment: @Skrillexazem убрал и ничего не поменялось(

Comment: Warning пишет??

Comment: Этим самым знаком вы подавили отображение ошибок, чего лучше не стоит делать если код перестает работать.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: @Skrillexazem warning не пишет

Comment: Файл слишком большой, => поставьте  value="3000000"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['go'])){
$uploaddir = 'avatars/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['picture']['name']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Файл корректен и был успешно загружен.\n";
} else {
    echo "Возможная атака с помощью файловой загрузки!\n";
}

echo 'Некоторая отладочная информация:';
print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<!-- Тип кодирования данных, enctype, ДОЛЖЕН БЫТЬ указан ИМЕННО так -->
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <!-- Поле MAX_FILE_SIZE должно быть указано до поля загрузки файла -->
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
    <!-- Название элемента input определяет имя в массиве $_FILES -->
    Отправить этот файл: <input name="picture" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить файл" name="go"/>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Сделал как у вас, посмотрите, дополнил ответ

Comment: Я ответил в чем причина под вопросом.

Comment: Заработало? (менять value надо в  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />)

Comment: да, заработало. спасибо

Comment: Без проблем. На будущее - https://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: А 3 000 000 - это в чем  измерение идет? в байтах?

Comment: Скрытое поле MAX_FILE_SIZE (значение необходимо указывать в байтах), я же скинул ссылку, почитали бы)