# Вывод аватара пользователя

Tags: php, html

Пользователи загружают у меня на сайте свои фотографии (для аватарок), но я не знаю как выдавать их обратно при оставлении пользователем комментария. Как это реализовать? Как-нибудь не мудрёно.. пожалуйста, чтобы можно было разобраться.

Comment: Пользователя загружают фотографии на сервер. Значит сервер и должен их "отдавать".. Как они у вас вообще сохраняются для пользователей?

Comment: А у вас в БД сайта есть таблица с пользователями? Вообще Базы Данных используются на сайте?

Comment: @Skrillexazem есть, там айди, логин и множество других столбцов. (2 уникальных столбца - логин и email)

Comment: @InDevX Сохраняются в папку на сервере следующим путем (см. лучший ответ): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/980014/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82

Comment: @Cool_cool вам надо создать таблицу для изображений, туда записывайте их данные + user_id по которому будете выводить картинки для пользователя (но лучше, конечно, fireign key использовать)

Comment: @InDevX А как это наглядно примерно будет выглядеть? какие данные записывать и как выводить по этому user id? Обычный вывод из таблицы я могу, но картинка то не в базе данных, отсюда у меня и вопрос

Comment: То есть вопрос возникает на этапе "Картинка загрузилась на сервер и что дальше"

Comment: @Cool_cool Смотрите. `user_id` это `id` с таблицы `users`. В таблицу для изображений можно записывать путь к файлу, имя файла и т.п.. И тогда просто запрос надо будет прописать что подставлялись данные с нужным id. Можно вообще картинку подписывать `[id].jpg` где [id] - id пользователя, соответственно. Вариантов много, в принципе.

Comment: @InDevX Я так и думал, что можно при загрузке пользователем подписывать его картинку как его id. Но как сделать, чтобы вывод был по определенному пути, а главное - чтобы при загрузке им картинки имя картинки было равно чему-то другому (код ровно тот же, что я кидал выше). Заранее спасибо за информацию

Comment: Переименовать просто... `if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {` <= тут `$uploadfile` это новое имя файла, как его измените, так файл и будет называться.. А насчет вывода.. Ну тут очень просто.. Вы если именуете файлы через id пользователя то база не нужна, а надо просто находить картинку по `пути/к_файлу/[user_id].png`.. Id юзера находите в базу и подставляете в путь. Профит